# How do i debounce a switch in c?

Tags: c, switch-statement, microcontroller, debouncing, mplab

Im having problems with debouncing a switch in c on MPLAB X IDE. I want to make something like a flashlight with one switch for on and off. Can somebody help me?
sorry for my bad englisch.

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#include <xc.h>
#include "pic16f1455.h"

/************************************************************
* Interrups/debouncing
*************************************************************/
/** Configuration ********************************************************/
// #pragma config statements should precede project file includes.
// Use project enums instead of #define for ON and OFF.



// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTOSC    // Oscillator Selection Bits (INTOSC oscillator: I/O function on CLKIN pin)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF       // Watchdog Timer Enable (WDT disabled)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer Enable (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON       // MCLR Pin Function Select (MCLR/VPP pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Flash Program Memory Code Protection (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset Enable (Brown-out Reset enabled)
#pragma config CLKOUTEN = OFF   // Clock Out Enable (CLKOUT function is disabled. I/O or oscillator function on the CLKOUT pin)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal/External Switchover Mode (Internal/External Switchover Mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enable (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled)



// CONFIG2
#pragma config WRT = OFF        // Flash Memory Self-Write Protection (Write protection off)
#pragma config CPUDIV = NOCLKDIV// CPU System Clock Selection Bit (NO CPU system divide)
#pragma config USBLSCLK = 48MHz // USB Low SPeed Clock Selection bit (System clock expects 48 MHz, FS/LS USB CLKENs divide-by is set to 8.)
#pragma config PLLMULT = 3x     // PLL Multipler Selection Bit (3x Output Frequency Selected)
#pragma config PLLEN = ENABLED  // PLL Enable Bit (3x or 4x PLL Enabled)
#pragma config STVREN = ON      // Stack Overflow/Underflow Reset Enable (Stack Overflow or Underflow will cause a Reset)
#pragma config BORV = LO        // Brown-out Reset Voltage Selection (Brown-out Reset Voltage (Vbor), low trip point selected.)
#pragma config LPBOR = OFF      // Low-Power Brown Out Reset (Low-Power BOR is disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF        // Low-Voltage Programming Enable (High-voltage on MCLR/VPP must be used for programming)



char statusFlag = 0;



void main(void)
{
    TRISA = 0b00110000;            
    TRISC = 0b00000000;
    ANSELA = 0b00000000;
    ANSELC = 0b00000000;
    IOCAN = 0b00100000;
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;           
    INTCONbits.IOCIE = 1;  

    
   PORTCbits.RC3 = 0;
    
    while(1)
    {
        if(statusFlag == 1)
        {
            if(PORTCbits.RC3 == 0)
            {
                PORTCbits.RC3 = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                PORTCbits.RC3 = 0;
            }
            statusFlag = 0;
        }
    }
}


void __interrupt() ISR(void)
{
    if(INTCONbits.IOCIF == 1)                       
    {
        INTCONbits.IOCIF = 0;
        if(IOCAF5 == 1)
        {
            IOCAF5 = 0;
            statusFlag = 1;
        }

    }
}
```

I tried it with a queue procedure and i expected it to work and debounce the switch completely but it only worked sometimes and i want something that works everytime.

Comment: You need to specify a _time_ in which a change in input is considered an ignorable bounce versus just fast typing.

Comment: A physical alternative it is read 2 inputs for 1 switch: one is true when the switch is in position A and the other input is true when switch is in position B.  Both inputs are false when the switch is in-between (research break-before-make switch).

Comment: Are you trying to interrupt on the state change of the I/O pin?  dont do that, if you feel the need for interrupts use it for a periodic timer.  that isr (or just poll it at first to figure out how to do it and maybe complete the homework assgnment) then samples the I/O and then you decide from that how to filter bounces, which is not universal it is specific to your board, your switch your mcu your sampling rate, etc.  It is analog.

Comment: sometimes it is as simple as a single sample can suffice in some situations, and in others you need to sample many, dozens of samples in a row looking for a series at the same level without a glitch.

Comment: and you cannot know before hand until you start doing this sampling and examining the pattern you get for what you think are single presses.  You may have to use a different switch or have to put an r/c filter on the board, etc.  and then of course tune that filter to the switch/mcu.  a scope would help but remember that it will affect the signal.

Comment: There is no point in telling us _"I tried it with a queue procedure"_ unless you show us what you tried.  It is useless information.  I can't even begin to imagine what that could even mean.  Elaborate or delete.

Comment: Be sure to declare `statusFlag` `volatile`. https://www.embedded.com/introduction-to-the-volatile-keyword/

Answer (score 1):

For the simplest form of debouncing, then create a cyclic timer interrupt triggering once every 5ms or so. From inside that ISR you need something like:

```c
void timer_isr (void)
{
  uint8_t tmp;
  static uint8_t prev;
  tmp = gpio_port;

  if(tmp == prev)
  {
    debounced = tmp;
  }
  prev = tmp;
}
```

Where `debounced` is declared at file scope as `static volatile uint8_t debounced=0;`. This is all under the assumption that the switch is active high = 1 when pressed.

Comment: do i need any library for this code because it wont recognise some of the things

Comment: @LuregnGianutt It's kind of pseudo code, you have to translate "gpio_port" to the specific PIC register, write the ISR as required by your compiler and naturally also include stdint.h.

Answer (score 0):

You should only use an interrupt on a switch if the response time is millisecond level critical or a even faster.  If it is a human pressing a button, don't bother.  If it is a limit switch or e-stop on some fast moving machinery, or a collision switch on a robot, then perhaps.

The way you would do that is to disable further interrupts in the interrupt handler so you do not get bounce repeats.  The interrupt handler can then deal with the time critical emergency, clear any pending interrupt, then start a timer that re-enables the interrupt after the debounce period.

In most cases that is unnecessary and you should use @Lundin's answer or look at the numerous other questions on this subject already on SO.

This can be implement *crudely* in your existing code thus:

```c
volatile char statusFlag = 0;

#define DEBOUNCE_MS 20

void main(void)
{
    TRISA = 0b00110000;            
    TRISC = 0b00000000;
    ANSELA = 0b00000000;
    ANSELC = 0b00000000;
    IOCAN = 0b00100000;
    INTCONbits.GIE = 1;           
    INTCONbits.IOCIE = 1;  


    PORTCbits.RC3 = 0;
    for(;;)
    {
        if( statusFlag )
        {
            PORTCbits.RC3 = !PORTCbits.RC3 ;
            statusFlag = 0;

            __delay_ms( DEBOUNCE_MS ) ;  // Debounce delay
            INTCONbits.IOCIE = 1;        // Re-enable IOC
        }
    }
}

void __interrupt() ISR(void)
{
    if(INTCONbits.IOCIF == 1)                       
    {
        INTCONbits.IOCIF = 0;
        if(IOCAF5 == 1)
        {
            INTCONbits.IOCIE = 1;  // Disable IOC interrupt

            IOCAF5 = 0;
            statusFlag = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

However your target has a single IOC interrupt for all GPIO, so if you wanted to do this for multiple interrupts it might be unsuitable.  I said it was crude. There are solutions to that but they become increasingly complex.  And as I said in this example there really is no need.

Moreover the use of a blocking delay in the main loop means that other work cannot be done. Again there are solutions to taht, but it will require additional code not provided by the rather basic xc.h, and for this application it is not warranted.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to debounce buttons in C is to wait for a certain delay, then check if the button is still pressed. The shorter the delay, the more responsive, but the less reliable. Try different delay lengths and see what works best for you and your flashlight. Something like this:

```
void __interrupt() ISR(void)
{
    if(INTCONbits.IOCIF == 1)                       
    {
        __delay_ms(100); // Wait for button to finish bouncing
        if(PORTAbits.RA5 == 0) // Check if button is still pressed
        {
            if(statusFlag == 1)
            {
                statusFlag = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                statusFlag = 1;
            }
        }
        IOCAbits.IOCAF5 = 0; // Reset interrupt bits
        INTCONbits.IOCIF = 0; // Reset interrupt bits
    }
}
```

Comment: Really, a delay in an interrupt handler.   A health warning in this answer.

Comment: @Clifford No problem in a system as simple as this. This blokes just trying to turn an LED on and off, I think he'll be ok.

Comment: No doubt it is a learning exercise, all the more reason not to teach bad habits. It will break more realistic projects of even moderate complexity, or real-time requirements.